# Symmetric Group $S_n$ is Generated by Consecutive Transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I am trying to show that $S_n = \langle \{(i,i+1) ~|~ i \in [1,n-1] \} \rangle = Q$.

I have that $S = \langle \{(i,j) ~|~ 1 \le i < j \le n-1\} \rangle = \langle T \rangle$ , so my goal is to show that $T \subseteq Q$. I discovered that $(i,i+2) = (, and so my hope is that this serves a base case. Through some examples I made the following conjecture:

$$(i,i+k) = \bigg(i+(k-1),i+k \bigg) \bigg(i+(k-2),i+(k-1) \bigg)...\bigg(i,i-1 \bigg)...\bigg(i+(k-2),i+(k-1) \bigg(i+(k-1),i+k \bigg)$$

Assuming that the formula holds for some natural number $k$,

$$\bigg(i,i+(k+1) \bigg) = \bigg(i,i+k \bigg) \bigg(i,i+(k+1),i+k \bigg)$$

This is where I got stuck. I am presently blanking: how can we write $\bigg(i,i+(k+1),i+k \bigg)$ as a product of "consecutive" transpositions? My other question is, is there a simpler way to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

Okay. I have since taken a look at the duplicate and come to realize that first proving $S_n$ can be generated by $\{(1,2),(1,3),...,(1,n)\}$ makes things considerably simpler I did this exactly as [Keith Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/genset.pdf) did it in his proof of theorem 2.2.

However, I think I might have proved theorem 2.3 (which is the problem I initially posed) slightly differently, but hopefully someone will correct me if I am wrong.  I am not sure it is correct, so here goes nothing.

First, notice that $(1,3) = (2,3)(1,2)(2,3)$ and therefore $(1,3)$ is in $Q$. Now, suppose that $(1,i) \in Q$ for all integers up to some $i \in [1,n-1]$. Then $(1,i+1) = (i,i+1)(1,i)(i,i+1)$ Since $(i,i+1) \in Q$ and $(1,i)$ is in $Q$ by hypothesis, it follows that $(1,i+1) = (i,i+1)(1,i)(i,i+1) \in Q$, and therefore $S_n = \langle \{(1,2),...,(1,n)\} \rangle \subseteq Q$.

This seems a little simpler than the proof given by Keith Conrad, which can be found the aforementioned link.

Comment: One technique is to show that your generating set is enough to generate the members of another, *more obvious* generating set -- like all transpositions, that sort of thing. Of course, this relies on you already knowing at least one generating set for $S_n$, Do you know any other generating sets of $S_n$?

Comment: @pjs36 The only generating that I have available is the one cited above, the set $T$. But isn't $T$ the set of all transpositions?

Comment: @pjs36 I edited my post to contain. Would you mind looking at the proof I gave?